# How to pause and resume StreamProvider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am experimenting on forex live update using `StreamProvider`.
The demo will auto-update the exchange rate by fetching latest data from external API periodically. (every 60 seconds in this example)

Below is the diagram of implementation.

**Diagram**

```
API call (Future event) --> Put data in stream
      ^                             |
      |                             V              
Wait for 60 seconds <--  StreamProvider listens for 
                        new event and rebuild widget
```

**Problem**

The stream continues even when navigating to main view.

If we use `StreamBuilder`, we may be able to call `listen()` method, which
will return `StreamSubscription`. Then, either `cancel()`, `pause()`, or `resume()` method can be called on demand.
I wonder if there is similar method to `pause` and `resume` while using `StreamProvider`?

**Expected**

`pause` when leaving dashboard view and `resume` when return to dashboard view.

**Codes**

Model

```dart
class Currency {
  String? base;
  String? quote;
  double? rate;

  // constructor, factory constructor, etc.
  // ...
}
```

Controller

```dart
class CurrencyService {
  Currency? _currency;

  Stream<Currency?> get currencyStream async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), (_) {
      return getCurrencyData();
    }).asyncMap((event) async => await event);
  }

  Future<Currency?> getCurrencyData() async {
    try {
      // Perform API call and 
      // update Currency object
      // ...
      
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
    return _currency;
  }
}
```

View

```dart
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // some providers,
        // another one,
        // ...
        StreamProvider<Currency?>(
          create: (_) => CurrencyService().currencyStream,
          initialData: await CurrencyService().getCurrencyData(),
        ),
      ],
      child: TestApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Live Update Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Main view (page 1)

```dart
class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainViewState createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // ...
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
            },
            child: Text('Dashboard')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Dashboard view (page 2)

```dart
class DashboardView extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Consumer<Currency?>(
      builder: (context, currency, child) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text('${currency?.base ?? ''}${currency?.quote ?? ''}'),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text('${currency?.rate ?? ''}'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: A `Stream.periodic` cannot be paused and resumed. It will run forever until closed, at which point it will be forever closed. Instead, use a `Timer` to run the periodic event and pass the data into a normal `StreamController` which your widgets can listen to.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the suggestion. I have revised some parts and it actually works. I will add the revision in Answer section below. Still I am curious and interested in similar implementation using `StreamProvider`

Comment: You can still use `StreamProvider`. Instead of using the default constructor, use `StreamProvider.value` to supply an external stream source.

Comment: @Abion47 I replace the `StreamBuilder` with `StreamProvider.value` and it finally works! It takes a while to figure out how to use it with `Timer.periodic`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing and resuming `StreamProvider` on `Stream.periodic` don't seem possible. Instead, the implementation can still be achieved using `Timer.periodic` and `StreamController`, as suggested by @Abion47

We can simulate the pause and resume by controlling when to start and stop adding new data to stream. One of the ways is to start the `Timer.periodic` when navigating to dashboard view (after a button is pressed) and `cancel` the timer when returning to main view (dashboard view is popped up).

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // start timer
    // ...
    Navigator.pushNamed(...).then((_) { 
      // stop timer
      // this section is triggered when returning from dashboard to main view
    });
}
```

**Revised codes**

```dart
// Controller

class CurrencyService {
  Currency? _currency;
  Timer? _pollingTimer;
  StreamController<Currency?> _currencyController = StreamController.broadcast();

  Future<void> addCurrencyData() async {
    await getCurrencyData()
        .then((currency) => _currencyController.add(currency));
  }

  void closeStream() {
    _currencyController.close();
  }

  void startPolling() {
    addCurrencyData();
    _pollingTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), (_) => addCurrencyData());
  }

  void stopPolling() {
    _pollingTimer?.cancel();
  }

  Stream<Currency?> get currencyStream => _currencyController.stream;

  Future<Currency?> getCurrencyData() async {
    try {
      // Perform API call and 
      // update Currency object
      // ...
      
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
    return _currency;
  }
}

// Main

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // some providers,
        // another one,
        // ...
        Provider(create: (_) => CurrencyService()),
      ],
      child: TestApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Live Update Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}

// Main view (page 1)

class MainView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // ...
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<CurrencyService>(context, listen: false)
                .startPolling();
              Navigator.pushNamed(
                context, 
                '/dashboard',
              ).then((_) => Provider.of<CurrencyService>(context, listen: false).stopPolling());
            },
            child: Text('Dashboard')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Dashboard view (page 2)

class DashboardView extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currencyService = Provider.of<CurrencyService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamProvider<Currency?>.value(
        initialData: null,
        value: currencyService.currencyStream,
        child: CurrencyRate(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CurrencyRate extends StatelessWidget {
  const CurrencyRate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currency = context.watch<Currency?>();
    return Center(
      child: currency == null
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text('${currency?.base ?? ''}${currency?.quote ?? ''}'),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text('${currency?.rate ?? ''}'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
         );   
      } 
}
```